# cant fetch city and district data due to a irrelevant error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database which contains city(sehir) and district(il) tables. In my registration form I want to fetch district data depending on city value. And there is a address table which has foreign keys to these tables. There is a column for postal code. First I made it integer value, when I tried it like this, my ajax call was working properly it was fetching all city and district data dynamically. But when I submitted form i got an error which says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'". I couldn't decide which value the error is mentioning. I've decided that it is postal code so I ve changed its type to varchar and updated it in my model class, when I did it this way, this time my ajax call was not working properly, the thing is that my ajax call has nothing to do with postal code. My Code:

Address Class:

```
public int kullaniciID { get; set; }
        public int? ulkeID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Şehir girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        public int sehirID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "İlçe girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        public int ilceID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Posta kodu girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Posta kodu maksimum 6 haneye sahip olabilir!")]
        public string postaKodu { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Açık adres girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [MinLength(30,ErrorMessage = "Açık adres en az 30 karaktere sahip olmak zorundadır")]
        public string acikAdres { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "İlçe gerekli")]
        public virtual tblİlce tblİlce { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı gerekli")]
        public virtual tblKullanici tblKullanici { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Şehir gerekli")]
        public virtual tblSehir tblSehir { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ülke gerekli")]
        public virtual tblUlke tblUlke { get; set; }
```

Method to fetch data from db with ajax(in User Controller):

```
public JsonResult IlIlce(int? ilID, string tip)
        {
            db = new DatabaseContext();
            List<SelectListItem> sonuc = new List<SelectListItem>();

            bool isSuccessful = true;

            try
            {
                switch (tip)
                {
                    case "ilGetir":
                        //veritabanımızdaki iller tablomuzdan illerimizi sonuc değişkenimze atıyoruz
                        foreach (var sehir in db.tblSehir.ToList())
                        {
                            sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = sehir.sehirAdi,
                                Value = sehir.sehirID.ToString()
                            });
                        }
                        break;

                    case "ilceGetir":
                        //ilcelerimizi getireceğiz ilimizi selecten seçilen ilID sine göre 
                        foreach (var ilce in db.tblİlce.Where(il => il.bagliOlduguSehirID == ilID).ToList())
                        {
                            sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = ilce.ilceAdi,
                                Value = ilce.ilceID.ToString()
                            });
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //hata ile karşılaşırsak buraya düşüyor
                isSuccessful = false;
                sonuc = new List<SelectListItem>();
                sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Bir hata oluştu :(",
                    Value = "Default"
                });

            }
            //Oluşturduğum sonucları json olarak geriye gönderiyorum
            return Json(new { ok = isSuccessful, text = sonuc });
        
    }
```

here is my register view, it contains jQuery code for ajax

```
@model IWP.Models.RegisterVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Kayıt Formu</h2>
<hr />

@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <span class="alert alert-danger">@ViewBag.Messsage</span>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "w-100 d-flex justify-content-center" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal p-5 m-3 w-50 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Kullanıcı adı</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.kullaniciAdi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.kullaniciAdi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Firma adı</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.firmaAdi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.firmaAdi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Şifre</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.sifre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "password" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.sifre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Şifre tekrar</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.sifreTekrar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "password" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.sifre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">E-mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "text" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Telefon</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.telefon, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.telefon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Bulunduğunuz il</label>
            <select class="form-control col-md-12" name="city" id="il" required></select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Bulunduğunuz ilçe</label>
            <select class="form-control col-md-12" name="district" id="ilce" disabled required>
                <option>Bir İl Seçiniz</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Posta kodunuz</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.postaKodu, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.postaKodu, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Açık adresiniz</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.acikAdres, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.acikAdres, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group w-100">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Kaydol" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            type: "post",
            url: "/User/IlIlce",//controllerımda gidicek olan yerim
            dataType: "json"
        });
        $.extend({
            ilGetir: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    //datamızı gönderiyoruz
                    data: { "tip": "ilGetir" },
                    success: function (sonuc) {
                        //gelen sonucumuz kontrol ediyoruz ona göre selectimze append işlemi gerçekleştiyoruz
                        if (sonuc.ok) {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#il").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        } else {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#il").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            ilceGetir: function (ilID) {

                $.ajax({
                    //ekstra olarak functionumaza gelen ilID mizi gönderiyoruz
                    data: { "ilID": ilID, "tip": "ilceGetir" },
                    success: function (sonuc) {
                        //bir önceki kayıtları temizliyorum
                        $("#ilce option").remove();
                        if (sonuc.ok) {
                            //disabled false yapıyorum
                            $("#ilce").prop("disabled", false);
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#ilce").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        } else {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#ilce").append(optionhtml);

                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //ilgetirimizi çalıştıyoruz
        $.ilGetir();
        //il selectimizde değişiklik olduğunda çalışacak func
        $("#il").on("change", function () {
            //seçili olan id alıyoruz
            var ilID = $(this).val();
            //seçili olan idmizi ilceGetir'imze gönderiyoruz
            $.ilceGetir(ilID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally my user model:

```
public partial class tblKullanici
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblKullanici()
        {
            this.tblBagis = new HashSet<tblBagis>();
            this.tblAdres = new HashSet<tblAdres>();
            this.tblSiparis = new HashSet<tblSiparis>();
        }
    
        public int kullaniciID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı adı girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı adınız 6 ila 30 karakter arasında olmak zorundadır!")]
        public string kullaniciAdi { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firma adı girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Firma adınız en fazla 70 karakter olabilir!")]
        public string firmaAdi { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Şifre girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(35,MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage =("Şifreniz 6 ila 35 karakter arasında olmak zorundadır"))]
        public string sifre { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan gereklidir!")]
        [Compare("sifre", ErrorMessage = "Şifreler uyuşmamaktadır!")]
        public string sifreTekrar { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [StringLength(70,ErrorMessage = "E-mail en fazla 70 karaktere sahip olabilir!")]
        public string mail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefon numarası girmeniz gerekmektedir!")]
        [MaxLength(16,ErrorMessage = "Telefon numaranız en fazla 16 haneli olabilir!")]
        public string telefon { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime olusturulmaTarihi { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblBagis> tblBagis { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblAdres> tblAdres { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblSiparis> tblSiparis { get; set; }
    }
```

District(ilce) model:

```
public partial class tblİlce
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblİlce()
        {
            this.tblAdres = new HashSet<tblAdres>();
        }
    
        public int ilceID { get; set; }
        public string ilceAdi { get; set; }
        public int bagliOlduguSehirID { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblAdres> tblAdres { get; set; }
    }
```

City(sehir) model:

```
public partial class tblSehir
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblSehir()
        {
            this.tblAdres = new HashSet<tblAdres>();
        }
    
        public int sehirID { get; set; }
        public string sehirAdi { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblAdres> tblAdres { get; set; }
    }
```

Register Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterVM model)
        {
            tblKullanici user = null;
            tblAdres address = null;

            if(model != null)
            {
                db = new DatabaseContext();
                user = model.User;
                address = model.Address;
                db.tblKullanici.Add(user);
                db.tblAdres.Add(address);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Kayıt işlemi sırasında hata oluştu!";
            return View(model);
            
        }
```

Thank you all for any kind of help from now..

Comment: I can't find  property  sehirAdi in your class

Comment: @Sergey sehirAdi property is in city(sehir) table.

Comment: Could you please show register action of user controller too? I need to see action that is  called on submit form.